# find null values in multidimensional associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to search through an associative array with an unknown number of dimensions and change all the null values to an empty string?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried?

Comment: why this question is down voted ? it is really a nice question . StackOverflow should Change the DownVote mechanism immediatly. ( maybe showing who is the downvoter  or supply a reason....). it cant go on like that

Comment: Yes there is. It is called Recursion.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on why this was down-voted as well. Is it because I failed to post non-functional code?

Comment: because "This question does not show any research effort" is the main reason why the questions are down-voted (hover over the "down vote" button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
var objectNullToEmpty = function (obj) {
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] === null) {
            obj[key] = '';
        }
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            objectNullToEmpty(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Comment: that's smart. thanks for the help! sorry i didn't sufficiently document my research.